# Java error : R cannot be resolved to a variable , Parsing Data for android-21 failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have searched for a solution to my problem on stack overflow . Before marking this question as duplicate, please understand that I have tried all the possible solutions that were posted, but I still have the above errors. I am running the default Hello World android program, so haven't made any changes in the code . The Minimum supported sdk version=8,Target build = sdk android API 21, Compiler sdk= android API 21 and Environment: Eclipse Juno.

Things that I tried : 
    -

1. I have deleted appcompat v4.jar from the appcompat workspace folder, which leaves me with just appcompat v7.jar
2. I have added appcompat_support_v7.jar as external jar.
3. I have tried refreshing, restarting eclipse and cleaning but errors still persist.
   Error being: "R cannot be resolved to a variable Type: Java Error".
4. For android 5,  JRE 1.8 is needed so I have installed that and set the windows environment variable to the path  where jdk1.8 is saved.
   i.e. JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
5. Using cmd when i do echo %JAVA_HOME% it prints the above path. Though I am still unable to run java programs from cmd using 'javac'.
6. I have then set the path for jdk1.8 by going to Eclipse, window>preference>java>installed jres , the path being : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31
7. I have also then gone to Eclipse, window>preference>java>installed jres>execution environment and checked the compatiability of SE 8.
8. Even after restarting Eclipse, the first error I get is :
   "Parsing Data for android-21 failed
   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0".
   and at the bottom in the problems tab ,the error I get is :

"R cannot be resolved to a variable -  Java Error"

9. My Android Support library is up to date and  I have installed all the necessary packages using SDK manager for Android API 17 and 21 .

Please note that I have JRE 6 ,7 and 8 installed on my computer because I am using those versions in another eclipse for J2EE, but in eclipse (Juno) for android I have set the path for jdk 1.8.

I think it has got something to do with Java installation, but I don't understand what exactly I have done wrong. It would be great if you could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are new to Android development. Please use Android Studio as it is the official IDE for Android development.

Comment: I was stuck at same issue but problem is in one of my XML file. it looks nice but looking carefully I saw something `@drawable@drawable/R.draw..` .. So check your recently edited XML's and also is R.java file generating? If not then must look in XML's

Answer (score 1):

As you did not mention this in your checklist I was wondering: did you make sure that you **do not** have any *uppercase* letter in your resources file names? For example if you have a drawable named myIcon.png, you should rename it my_icon.png

I spent hours with a completely broken project just because of that, I wish this could be as simple in your case!?

Comment: Yes I do not have any uppercase letter in any file name for the files contained within the folders in res .

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that **appcompat_support_v7.jar** really is pointing to the right location by going under project -> properties.

2) Clean (even though you've done it already)

Comment: Yes, on going to Project>Properties>java BuildPath , android-support-v7-appcompat.jar is pointing to the correct location where the jar file is actually located i.e. in C:\Program Files\android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs